# tkinter delete on focusin

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I have been studying validatecommand patterns like in this post:

[Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter/4140988#4140988)

My question is that one of the actions on an entry widget that triggers the callback is 'focusin'.

I would like to use this to clear the contents of the entry, however, the entry object does not appear to be not passed to the callback.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there another way to wire the focusin event for an entry widget and still be able to execute validation?

Of course I could hard code entry.delete but I want it to work for any entry widget on the GUI.

```
def onValidate(self, d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
    if self._is_number(S):
        return True
    else:
        self.bell()
        return False

def _add_widgets(self):
    vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
    self.f_entry = ttk.Entry(self.window, width=5, validate="all", textvariable=self.fahrenheit, validatecommand=vcmd).grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The validation feature should be used only for validation. If you want to delete when the widget gets focus you should set a binding on the `<FocusIn>` event.